# What does the following code produce?

Tags: c++

I don't know if this is a trick question or what, but when I try to run this piece of code, I get a few errors.  Do you think the teacher forgot to put in an #include line?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int display(int val) {
    cout << val << ",";
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {1, -4, 5, -100, 15, 0, 5};
    vector<int> v(a, a + 7);

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater<int>());
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), display);
}
```

.

```
g++ -ggdb  -c test.cpp
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:13:41: error: 'sort' was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:14:38: error: 'for_each' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

Thanks

Comment: In the future when you get errors like these you can search a c++ reference, like I did for [sort()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), usually you'll see at the top which header it is defined in.

Answer (score 8):

> Do you think the teacher forgot to put in an #include line?

**Yes.**

He definitely forgot to:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

That's the Standard Library header for algorithms such as `std::sort` and `std::for_each`, which is precisely what your compiler complains about.

Incidentally, despite the fact that your compiler *didn't* complain about this (yet), he also forgot to:

```
#include <functional>
```

That's the Standard Library header for functors such as `std::greater<>`, which you make use of here.

Besides, your (teacher's?) `display()` function should have `void` as its return type, as it currently returns no value.

Comment: @ildjarn: Correct, good catch. I can't edit my answer now (typing on mobile), feel free to add that if you wish.

Comment: Re: `display()` not returning a value: sloppy but harmless here. :-( Its return type should be `void`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to `#include <algorithm>` for `std::sort` and `std::for_each`, which is most likely what you are trying to call when you say `sort` and `for_each`. The effect of the algorithm is to sort array `a` in increasing order and print the elements to stdout.